# Adding metabox to wordpress plugins menu page

Tags: metabox

Now I am building a wordpress plugin. I need to add a metabox to the admin submenu page. I tried like this below,

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_boxs');
function add_meta_boxs()
{
    add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'My First Meta Box', 'meta_box', 'myContactForm', 'normal', 'high' );
}
```

I created a submenu page:

```
add_submenu_page( 'myForm',  'Add New' , 'Add New', 'manage_options', 'newForm', 'newform_page');

function newform_page()
    {
       <div class="form-container-2">
        <?php do_meta_boxes('myContactForm', 'normal', null); ?>
        </div>
    }
```

Here "myContactForm" is a custom post type.
Meta box was created in custom post type but what I need is meta box will be created within submenu page.

Anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Meta box are designed to work with Post(s) and Custom post types.

However you can make it work on options page if you know what you are doing.

[Click here](https://gist.github.com/bueltge/757903) for sample code